# Lua callback from C++

Tags: c++, lua

I have a c++ host in which I use tolua++ to expose some classes to Lua. One of the classes has a function that should register a callback from lua. So when the C++ code needs to call a Lua registered function it can. The function is however a table/class function. I've done this before with the string function name (not part of a lua "class") with success but I'm curious if I'm able to somehow store the Lua function and not function name.

I define my lua classes like:

```
MyClass = {}

function MyClass:Create()
    local obj = {}

    -- copy all functions from MyClass table to this local obj and return it
    local k,v
    for k,v in pairs(obj) do
        obj[k] = v
    end

    return obj
end

function MyClass:Enter()
    self.CPlusClass = CPlusClass:Create()   -- this is the C++ class creation, I defined a static function Create()
    self.CPlusClass:RegisterCallback(15, self.Callback) -- this is where I want to pass this instances function to be called back from the C++ class
end

function MyClass:Callback(reader)
    -- I want to be able to use self here as well so it needs to be the same instance
end
```

Inside the MyClass:Enter() is where I want to register the lua "class" function MyClass::Callback to be able to be called from the C++ object. How would I pass this into a C++ function? What would the type be so that it will call MyClass:Callback() from C++ also passing in "self" so that it's the same "instance" of the class?

So I know 'self' is referring to an actual variable that I created and I assume will be in the global table by variable name, but when you are inside the lua "class" how can I tell what variable name 'self' is referring too? If I could get that I could pass that to my C++ function and store it as a string so that I can call getglobal on it to get that specific table, and then I could also pass the table function name as string and in C++ I could get that also, and call it. But the question would be, how can I convert 'self' to the actual variable name it's pointing too so I can call getglobal in C++ to get that table?

Comment: `self` is not a global, self is an automatic variable defined by the `table:function` syntactic sugar. `function table:class(args...) ... end` is identical to `function table.class(self, args...) ... end`. Similarly a call to `tab:class(args...)` is identical to `tab.class(tab, args...)` (though tab is evaluated only once).

Comment: I understand that. self however is referring to a table I created somewhere in my lua program. How can I tell what variable name self is referring to?

Comment: You can't disassociate a function from its table "object" and have it work on that table "object" again later. You would need to create a closure as your callback function to do what you wanted to do here.

Comment: `self` is the variable name. It is the first argument to the function. It is the table on which the function is called.

Comment: but self is referring to a table I created somewhere in the lua program is it not? that table variable name must be in the global table is it not?

Comment: Perhaps running the following will help you get a sense of what I mean. lua -e 'local a = {cb = function(self) print("manual self cb", self) end} function a:cb2() print("automatic self cb", self) end a.cb(a) a:cb2()'

Comment: Yes, `self` is referring to whatever table you used in your `tab:Callback()` call. Which table you created earlier in a call to `local tab = MyClass.Create()`.

Comment: so, I may have created 5 instances of MyClass this way. I don't create them as local so all their variable names must exist in the global table right? now, when I'm inside a function in MyClass and using self, I don't know what actual table variable name it's pointing to, but if I did, I could send that name to my C++ class and call getglobal() on it to get the table from within C++ right? Then I could get the function by name as well and call it, passing that table as the first param to satisfy the self param. The question is can I get the global variable name self is referring to?

Comment: You should be using locals. You could do something like what you wanted if you wanted to compare self against all the visible globals to find the one that matched. You don't want to do that. That's a terrible methodology. What you want to do, to solve your problem with the least amount of changes, is create a closure in `:Enter` something like `function create_closure(obj, fun) return function(...) return obj[fun](...) end end` and then use `self.CPlusClass:RegisterCallback(15, create_closure(self, "Callback"))`.

Comment: Creating closures like this does create extra garbage. If this is something you are going to be doing a lot of in your program then you may want to reconsider your callback registration mechanism so that it better supports an object-specific callback.

Comment: OK, so if I wanted to do it the way I was thinking there is no "easy" way and I'd have to loop over _G looking for what matches self and go from there. I agree I'd prefer not to do that. I was hoping there was an easier way. So what is actually being passed to RegisterCallback in the second param then? I don't know anything about closures but what I can gather is that I'm returning an anonymous lua function that calls my self objects function. How would I handle that on the C++ side?

Comment: Your globals are no different than other globals. So, yes, unless you keep a registry of created objects the only place you can find them is the globals table (assuming they are even there). With my suggested code the second argument to `RegisterCallback` is still a function. It just happens to be an anonymous function that calls some other function when it is run. But the code that calls it doesn't need to (and doesn't) know anything about any of that. It just calls the callback function.

Comment: So basically it's creating a global function that when called will always refer to my object and function that I passed in when creating it. If it doesn't have a name, how would I call that from C++? What is the param type in my C++ class that I'm storing this in? Basically what does a closure return and how would C++ store it and refer back to it and call it at a later date.

Comment: It is creating an anonymous function; it has no name. That function, when called, will always call the callback of the object given to `create_closure`. Call `create_closure` on some different object and you get a function that will call the callback for that object. Call `create_closure` on the same object again and you get a *different* function that calls the callback on that same object. The closure is a function. How were you planning to store the callback function in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the `RegisterCallback` signature and operation (as opposed to enhancing it to understand object method callbacks in some fashion) then you need to create a closure and pass that as the callback. Something like this:

```
function create_closure(obj, fun)
    return function(...)
        return obj[fun](...)
    end
end
```

and

```
function MyClass:Enter()
    self.CPlusClass = CPlusClass:Create()   -- this is the C++ class creation, I defined a static function Create()
    self.CPlusClass:RegisterCallback(15, create_closure(self, "Callback"))
end
```

Comment: My 2nd param to RegisterCallback() was actually a string. My original hope was to be able to get the variable name self was referring to and concat it like "obj:Callback" and then break it out in the C++ function. What would the second param need to be if I did this method?

Comment: `RegisterCallback` takes a string? It assumes that names a global function that can be looked up later?

Comment: It's a string because my thought process was to be able to lookup the table name that has the function, which would mean it's assuming it's global. I'm the only one working with this so I control that. However changing the param isn't a huge deal, but I'd just need to know what a closure returns and what type my C++ function would be expecting. Also, my C++ program would be passing 1 parameter of a lightuserobject to the closure. I assume the ... handles all the params automatically?

Comment: The closure doesn't return anything for this purpose. The closure *is* the return from create_closure and a closure is just a function. You can't store a lua function in C++ directly (unless your binding handles the necessary work for you). What you store is a reference to the function in a known table and then look it up again when you need it. See luaL_ref in the lua manual for a lua api example of this idea. Yes, ... is lua varargs.

Comment: So the point of this is to be able to call a lua function from C++, so I would have to store something in C++ to be able to call it at some point from C++. In the past without classes I would pass in the string name of a lua function so that I could get it and call it from C++. Now that this is a "class" function, I still need to store something to be able to call it later from C++. Since it's anonymous it doesn't have a name, but I assume it's in the global table somewhere (just no name?). Does lua behind the scenes give it some value that I can lookup in C++ to call it or something?

Comment: No. It is not in the globals table (or any other table). It is only in the variable you assign it to. In the `RegisterCallback` case it exists only in the argument list of the `RegisterCallback` function. You need to take the function you get, store it somewhere you can find it later, then retrieve it from there at that later point at call it. Again, see luaL_ref in the lua manual (your binding almost certainly has something similar).

Comment: If I can use luaL_ref to get a unique id for the function, can't I do the same thing if I pass in self also or will the self value not be the same as the ref value it's referring to?

Comment: You could the `self` variable in `:Enter` to `RegisterCallback`, sure. That would get you a table "object" and not a function though. You could use that with luaL_ref just fine though. How you get from that table "object" to the function to call is the question at that point.

Comment: I'm thinking I would pass in both self as is, and then the function name as a string and store both in C++. Then when I need to call I get the table self is referring to, and then push to get the function name that is inside that table, and then call it. Lua call would look like RegisterCallback(15, self, "Callback"). I'm just curious if self and the actual object share the same luaL_ref(). I'm assuming they do.

Comment: It would seem to me that using luaL_ref() is the best way to pass things around as it seems like it's basically an integer id for lua "objects". Sounds like it's a way to id any object in lua? That's really the main issue here. Finding lua objects somehow.

Comment: Indeed. Changing `RegisterCallback` to accept an object and a callback would work just fine if you store a ref to the object and the string then simulate the `obj:fun()` call.

Comment: This is the idea I need, but I have no idea how to set this up in C++ using tolua++. Right now I'm trying lua_Object as the param type that I pass self into, but the tolua++ binding is failing when it checks that param against tolua_isnoobj(). Not sure why. I tried changing that check to tolua_istable() but it still fails.

Answer (score 3):

You exported CPlusClass "class" from C++ to Lua: surely this C++ class has a RegisterCallback which accepts a pointer to a function or to a YourCallbackClass instance which uses virtual methods to dispatch to the correct object. Then all you need is to export YourCallbackClass to Lua: behind the scenes, the Lua version will create an instance and give it to your C++ RegisterCallback. 
For instance:

```
class CPlusClass {
public: 
    RegisterCallback(int val, CPlusCallback* cb) { ... store cb for later... }
};

class SomeObj; // type of Objects that you want to call back into

class CPlusCallback {
public:
    typedef void (SomeObj::*Method)();
    CPlusCallback(SomeObj* obj, Method method) { callee=obj; method=method; }
    call() { callee->*Method(); }
private:
    SomeObj* callee; 
    Method method;
};
```

Your CPlusCallback is likely different, this is just an example. For example if you just want functions not methods then you don't need to store the callee. If you want both, then CPlusCallback must be a base class and the call() is virtual, with the derived classes implementing the details as appropriate. Adapt to your situation.

Then export CPlusCallback and SomeObj to Lua, then you can do in Lua:

```
somObj = SomeObj:Create()

function MyClass:Enter()
    -- creates Lua instance of CPlusClass, with a user data for the C++
    -- counterpart as member
    self.CPlusClass = CPlusClass:Create()  
    self.CPlusCallback = CPlusCallback:Create(someObj, someObj.method)
    self.CPlusClass:RegisterCallback(15, self.CPlusCallback)
end
```

where the above assumes that someObj.method is a method you exported, from C++ class SomeObj, with the proper signature void (SomeObj::*Method)().

Comment: Thanks for an alternative method. Currently I got the method of sending self, then a string method name of the lua class and calling it back from C++. Very similar to what you did here. I was concerned with the details on how it's done but I figured it out.